# What manga is this quote from?

Tags: identification-request

An awkward picture so I hid it below. I found it on Facebook. When Google searching, I couldn't find any specifics.

> [image]

From which manga is this from with that specific quote? I would love to find out what it is and read it.

Answer (score 5):

Your image is a collage from a scene in the second chapter of a 3-chapter short BL series named [**Light Blue Triangle**](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=34901) (Japanese title: みずいろ三角). It is collected along with 2 other stories into tankoubon under the title [*Konna Nekomimi, Suki desu ka?*](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=46638)

This is the page which the image comes from:

[image]

In the manga, what he actually said is along the line of:

> Shut up! You don't know anything at all!

So what you have is confirmed a collage.

---

The image was reposted on [this thread](https://archive.moe/a/thread/86132936/#86166234), as [@Secret Evil Radio](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/9554/secret-evil-radio) has pointed out. However, the first identification was incorrect, and the actual series was pointed out at [the end of the reply chain](https://archive.moe/a/thread/86132936/#86200155):

> Now I searched through the internet archive (since that Tumblr account deleted his posts) and found out that the title is *Konna Nekomimi, Suki desu ka?*. It's a collection of stories.

Answer (score 4):

My best guess for you would have to be a manga that goes by the name **Boku no Ano Ko**. I can't confirm this for you for sure because I don't have access to the manga to read, but searching for images reveals a character that

- appears visually similar to the one in the picture you've provided, and, incidentally,
- enjoys homosexual activities.

The manga is a yaoi, so the dialogue content of the frame you provided fits.

Below is a frame I found for you to consider. The manga is NSFW.

[image: frame / manga excerpt]

**EDIT**: That picture is apparently an edit. [Here's](https://archive.moe/a/thread/86132936/#86199457) the source.

Comment: I have went through the 3 available chapters in English, and can't find the frame above.

Comment: @nhahtdh It also looks a lot like Light from Death Note. I'd check out that one next.

Comment: I finally found the source of the image. It's from Light Blue Triangle.